# Tensor product of bialgebras in a braided monoidal category

Tags: reference-request, examples-counterexamples, monoidal-categories, hopf-algebras

Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes,\mathbb{I},\alpha,\lambda,\rho,c)$ be a braided monoidal category. By this I mean a (not necessarily strict) monoidal category $(\mathcal{C},\otimes,\mathbb{I},\alpha,\lambda,\rho)$ together with an invertible brading
$$c_{X,Y}:X\otimes Y \to Y\otimes X.$$
In $\mathcal{C}$ we can consider two bialgebras $A$ and $B$ and their tensor product $A\otimes B$. It is well-known that *if the braiding is symmetric* (i.e. if $c^2=\mathsf{id}$) then $A\otimes B$ has a natural structure of bialgebra and *it seems to me that it is folklore* that in general this is not true. After long computations with braided diagrams, I convinced myself that one really needs the symmetry condition, whence now I would like to ask:

> **Question 1:** Do there exist examples of bialgebras in braided monoidal categories whose tensor product is not a bialgebra anymore?
>
> **Question 2:** Is there a trustful reference in which this is explicitly claimed?

Comment: I remember doing computations with string diagrams at some point and convincing myself that the tensor product of two algebra objects was again an algebra object. Do you agree with that? Does this fail to be true for bialgebra objects?

Comment: @Joppy The tensor product of two algebra objects should be an algebra object, so I agree with you. You can also define comultiplication and counit on the tensor product of two coalgebra objects and that is a coalgebra again. The problems start to arise when you try to show that multiplication/comultiplication are compatible.